# JSX Full Navbar Size

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, next.js, jsx

Why when I make a navbar using next.js with react that the navbar isn't the full length? Like why isn't the navbar width 100%?

Here is the SCSS Styles:

```
$color-navbar-text: #000000;
$color-navbar-border: #303030;
$color-navbar-background: #707070;

/* Styles */
.navbar {

  color: $color-navbar-text;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 7.5%;
  background: $color-navbar-background;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .nList {

    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;

    .nlItem {

      .nliLink {

        margin: 0px 25px;
        text-decoration: none;

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Here is the JSX component:

```
import Link from "next/link";

import moduleStyles from "../styles/Navbar.module.scss";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (

    <nav
      className = { moduleStyles.navbar }
    >
      <h3>
        Hello
      </h3>
      <ul
        className = { moduleStyles.nList }
      >
        <li
          className = { moduleStyles.nlItem }
        > 
          <Link
            href = "/"
          >
            <a
              className = { moduleStyles.nliLink }
            >
              Home
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li
          className = { moduleStyles.nlItem }
        >
          <Link
            href = "/"
          >
            <a
              className = { moduleStyles.nliLink }
            >
              Home
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li
          className = { moduleStyles.nlItem }
        >
          <Link
            href = "/"
          >
            <a
              className = { moduleStyles.nliLink }
            >
              Home
            </a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button>
        Login
      </button>
    </nav>

  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

I don't know how the navbar isn't full size because when I worked on another project it is full size. I think it might have to do with the flexbox or something.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXzfs.jpg)

Comment: You need `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that it was that simple. Thank you!!! That really helped!